# Extract data till the first occurrence of a specific "Text" in R

Tags: r

Below is the sample data.

**ColumnA**

1. 911 is the national emergency number in Canada.Kids Help Phone is a nationwide 24-hour, toll-free, confidential crisis line and counselling service available to Canadians under the age of twenty.
2. 112 and 199 are the national emergency numbers in Cyprus.Cyprus Samaritans  is available every day from 4pm to 12am and is confidential. They can be reached at 8000 7773.

**Result** "sentence till the first occurrence of `national emergency number` in all rows", shown below:

**ColumnA**

1. 911 is the national emergency number
2. 112 and 199 are the national emergency numbers

I tried this but it is not giving appropriate result:

```
stri_extract(HelpLine$HelpLineNo, regex='[^national]*')->a
stri_extract_first_regex(HelpLine$HelpLineNo, "^[^emergency]+")->a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `stringr` solution assuming you want to include the optional "s" if there are multiple numbers:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(HelpLine$HelpLineNo,".*national emergency number[s]?") -> a
a
# [1] "911 is the national emergency number"           "112 and 199 are the national emergency numbers"
```

If you want to learn more about extracting data based on patterns, check out `regular expressions`.  I use this cheat sheet when i'm doing regular expressions in R: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf